# Magento 2 Ebizmarts/MailChimp

Tags: magento2, mailchimp

I have installed MailChimp extension from reference link but getting errors below :-

https://marketplace.magento.com/mailchimp-mc-magento2.html

> Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/html/austinsdiving/app/code/Ebizmarts/MailChimp/etc/module.xml):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

Friontend:-

https://prnt.sc/jfnek2

Compile Time:-

> [ReflectionException]              Class Mailchimp does not exist

https://prnt.sc/jfnkjl

Please help me

Comment: It is simply the folder's permission problem. Please check and fix the folders permission and try again.

Comment: This happens because their extension sucks. Even their installation guide is not clear, they start by guiding you to download the extension via the market place, and then proceed to install it via the admin panel. Other extensions I found can always be installed by one of the following: composer, admin->marketplace, download and upload manually into app/data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to also require mailchimp lib, you can install by below command.

```
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that it may require other core library. I think first you need to install **ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib** package using composer.

```
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed same issue with composer command.

```
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

You can also download zip folder of library.

https://api.github.com/repos/ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib/zipball/293960203ff1d834af5b2f2726f03063494a2265